# Node.js driving things in right order in basic code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am struggling with node.js asynchronous world, I am noob in node.js. I don't understand how to drive basic program flow. I use package iotdb-arp to print ip adress and mac adress on network. I need to run this code, execute function scan, wait until variable arr is full then print that arr and ending message. I know that I should use callbacks but I am really lost. Could someone point me to right direction, how to run things in right order? Now when I execute that it prints "[+] Program start", then it prints "IP of this machine is : 192.168.1.2" then scan is executed but program is simultaneously in the end, arr is empty because scan is still running. Here is my code:

```
console.log("[+] Program start");
var ip = require('ip');
var browser = require('iotdb-arp');
var arr = [];

var myIp = ip.address();

console.log("IP of this machine is : " + myIp.toString());

function scan(){
browser.browser({},function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("#", error);
    } else if (data) {
        console.log(data);  
        arr.push(data); 

    } else {

    }    
});
}

/*function callback(){
  console.log(arr);  
  console.log("[+] Program End");
}*/

scan();
console.log(arr); // Here in the end i need print arr
console.log("[!] Program End"); // Here I need print message "[+] Program End"
```

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to use callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The function parameter in the "browser" call is a callback. Which means that when the "browser" function end , it is calling the parameter function you inserted. This is what you have to do in your "scan" function.

```
console.log("[+] Program start");
var ip = require('ip');
var browser = require('iotdb-arp');
var arr = [];

var myIp = ip.address();

console.log("IP of this machine is : " + myIp.toString());

function scan(callb){
browser.browser({},function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("#", error);
        callb(err);
    } else if (data) {
        console.log(data);  
        arr.push(data); 

    } else {
       callb()
    }    
});
}


scan(function(err){
  if(err) {return;} /// handle error here
  else {
   console.log(arr); // Here in the end i need print arr
   console.log("[!] Program End"); // Here I need print message "[+] Program End"
}


});
```

Comment: Thank you Dion, it is lot better, but still it looks like that callb() is executed 2 times. So I am getting "[!] Program end" 2 times.This is short example of my output:{ ip: '192.168.1.1',
  mac: '9C:5C:8E:C7:44:88',
  interface: 'en0',
  seen: 1486054726758 }
[!] Program End
{ ip: '192.168.1.1',
  mac: '9C:5C:8E:C7:44:88',
  interface: 'en0',
  seen: 1486054729261 }
[!] Program End